# Fail to install homebrew

Tags: linux, curl, homebrew

when i try to install homebrew using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I got the error like this:

```
curl: (56) SOCKS5 read error occurred
```

I fetch in Google but can't search the answer, what's wrong?

Comment: according to [the docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) - error 56 =  Failure with receiving network data.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
*This answer doesn't explain the OP's issue. However, for future readers, it's good to know.*

The original Homebrew was designed for macOS and it doesn't run properly on Linux.
However, the good news is there is a Linux port that is named (how else?) [`Linuxbrew`](http://linuxbrew.sh/).

In order to install it you have to run a similar command, only the origin of the script is different:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install)"
```

Read more on it's [homepage](http://linuxbrew.sh).